# Is there any way to guard against using an unchecked std::optional?

Tags: c++, stdoptional

For my purposes, I need to be able to say that my access to the `.value` of an optional is guaranteed to be valid. In the past, I have used a macro that checked against the `.has_value()` and called `return T` to jump out of execution, and then instantiated a local reference to the return of `.value`, as that meant that I never directly called `.value` myself, and only after a macro did the checked work. However, the same safety rules I am working under which do not allow me to call `.value` directly, also limit me to not use macros as they are also deemed unsafe.

Is there any way to conditionally either construct an object on the stack or return in the C++ language?

I have considered using `.and_then(...)`, but in the case of two optionals needed at once, the code swiftly becomes unreadable (which is another safety metric I must pass).

EDIT: other limitations:

- I have to use C++14 at the latest.
- I cannot use exceptions.
- No heap usage.
- No "hiding" the access to value or has_value.
- Removing the usage of optionals is possible, but I am looking for options to not remove them as the effort involved in changing a codebase which uses them liberally to one which does not is a lot of work. As far as I can see from comments and answers so far, it looks like there is no way to keep the way we code "Rust-like".
- The Y of the XY problem is: We want to be able to claim there are no terminates in any of the reachable code branches.
- The X is this, we want to not have to worry about the terminate which does exist in the `.value` call by claiming our code never actually calls it without first verifying by using `.has_value`

Comment: This reads like an XY-problem. Why are you using std::optional, if the local rules make using std::optional unusable? If you are maintaining existing code using std::optional, how does this existing code follow the rules?

Comment: If you need guaranteed validity then the function should return the value directly, not an optional. You can always add a `template<type_t> [[nodiscard]] auto get_manadatory_value(const std::optional<type_t>& optional)...` function and call that. (basically replacing your macro with a typesafe function)

Comment: Note that `std::optional<T>::value()` is always checked. Calling `.value()` on an unset optional is defined behavior and throws exception. For unchecked access, consider using `.operator*()`.

Comment: If you really must protect against use of an unchecked optional, don't provide `std::optional` directly to client code. Instead, write another class (which may use `std::optional` privately, but not expose it) that only provides checked operations, and throws on any attempt to access a non-existent value.   `std::optional` is specified in a way that relies on it being used correctly (e.g. `o.has_value()` is checked before calling `o.value()`).  [Personally, I'd be more concerned about prospects of other developers not accepting responsibility if they don't check things properly].

Comment: @Peter No need to check and throw, just return `o.value()` directly – as Mestkon highlighted, that already *is* checking and throwing – the argument for still wrapping is to hide the unchecked operators (`*` and `->`) away from the user so that it cannot circumvent calling `value`.

Comment: In a general scenario, where it *is* meaningful to check explicitly (e.g. wanting to avoid rather expensive exception handling) then on success these operators should be used instead to avoid double-checking ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `value` (or `has_value`) directly. Use `transform` and `and_then` for the single optional case, and the following for the multiple argument case.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_optional : std::false_type{};

template <typename T>
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T>
concept Optional = is_optional<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value;

template <typename F, Optional... Opts>
auto transform(F&& f, Opts&&... opts)
{
    return (opts && ...) ? std::optional{std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), *std::forward<Opts>(opts)...)} : std::nullopt;
}

template <typename F, Optional... Opts>
auto and_then(F&& f, Opts&&... opts)
{
    return (opts && ...) ? std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), *std::forward<Opts>(opts)...) : std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: I agree about not using value or has_value directly. Also, I'm unable to use C++17 features like the fold on the opts. I really like this solution though.

Comment: @RichardFabian oh, are you using boost::optional? [Adapted for C++14](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40c103636a9bb9c2)

Comment: No, but probably something similar. Ours works with C++11, but we are allowed to write with C++14 features now.